# PyQt5 - How to calculate corner points of a QGraphicsRectItem after rotation by its center point?

Tags: pyqt5, rotation, qt5

My problem is that I couldn't find the pixel values of each corner points of a HighwayItem (which is a QGraphicsRectItem) after rotation it by angle *theta* about the center point of it.

I used the Rotation Matrix which explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_computer_graphics#Rotation) and I also looked [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86755/how-to-calculate-corner-positions-marks-of-a-rotated-tilted-rectangle#:%7E:text=The%20essence%20is%20this%3A,via%20the%20trig%20formulas%20cited.)explanation. But, I cannot find the true values.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Here is MapViewer() class. A HighwayItem is created in this view.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QPointF, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, \
                            QGraphicsView, QGraphicsPixmapItem, \
from class_graphical_items import HighwayItem

class MapViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent, ui):
        super(MapViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = ui

        # Attributes for highway
        self.add_highway_control = False
        self.current_highway = None
        self.start = QPointF()
        self.hw_counter = 0

        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._map = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._map)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)


     def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._map.isUnderMouse():
            if self.add_highway_control:
                # Create a yellow highway
                self.current_highway = HighwayItem(self._scene, self.ui)
                self.hw_counter += 1
                self.start = self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint()
                r = QRectF(self.start, self.start)
                self.current_highway.setRect(r)
                self._scene.addItem(self.current_highway)

                # When adding HW, set drag mode NoDrag
                self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        super(MapViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)
     

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.add_highway_control and self.current_highway is not None:
            # When adding HW, set drag mode NoDrag
            self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)

            r = QRectF(self.start, self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint()).normalized()
            self.current_highway.setRect(r)
        super(MapViewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.add_highway_control:
            if self.current_highway is not None:
                # When finish the adding HW, set drag mode ScrollHandDrag
                self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

                self.update_item_dict(self.current_highway)
                self.update_item_table(self.current_highway)

            self.current_highway = None
            self.add_highway_control = False
        super(MapViewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

This is the HighwayItem class. It has some specs like color, opacity etc.

By doubleclicking on created HighwayItem, I'm activating a spinbox which was in a QTreeWidget in main window (ui).
By changing the spinbox value, the user can rotate the item.

```py
class HighwayItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, scene, ui):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self)
        self.scene = scene
        self.ui = ui

        self.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow)
        self.setOpacity(0.5)
        self.setZValue(4.0)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    # Here, I'm activating the spinbox by double clicking
    # on HighwayItem. In spinbox, I'm entering the rotation angle
    # of HighwayItem.
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        
        selected_item = self.scene.selectedItems()

        if selected_item:
            for i in range(self.ui.treeWidget_objects.topLevelItemCount()):
                toplevel_item = self.ui.treeWidget_objects.topLevelItem(i)
                heading_item = toplevel_item.child(2)
                spinbox = self.ui.treeWidget_objects.itemWidget(heading_item, 2)

                if str(toplevel_item.text(2)) == str(selected_item[0]):
                    if 'HighwayItem' in str(selected_item[0]):
                        spinbox.setEnabled(True)
                    else:
                        spinbox.setEnabled(False)
```

This is the HWHeadingSpinBox() class which sets the rotation angle of HWItem. My problem starts here. In rotate_hw() method, I am transforming the created HighwayItem by its center point and giving it a rotation by its center point.

BUT, when I try to calculate new corners of hw in calc_rotated_coords() method, I'm messing up.

```py
class HWHeadingSpinBox(QSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, viewer, selected_hw):
        QSpinBox.__init__(self)
        self.selected_hw = selected_hw
        self.viewer = viewer

        # First coords of HW
        tl = self.selected_hw.rect().topLeft()
        tr = self.selected_hw.rect().topRight()
        br = self.selected_hw.rect().bottomRight()
        bl = self.selected_hw.rect().bottomLeft()
        self.temp_list = [tl, tr, br, bl]

        self.setRange(-180, 180)
        self.setSuffix('°')
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.valueChanged.connect(self.rotate_hw)

    def heading_val(self):
        return self.value()

    def rotate_hw(self):
        angle = self.heading_val()
        self.selected_hw.prepareGeometryChange()
        offset = self.selected_hw.boundingRect().center()   
        self.selected_hw.sceneBoundingRect().center()
        transform = QTransform()
        transform.translate(offset.x(), offset.y())
        transform.rotate(-angle)
        transform.translate(-offset.x(), -offset.y())
        self.selected_hw.setTransform(transform)


        # br_rect = self.selected_hw.sceneBoundingRect()
        # sbr_rect = self.selected_hw.sceneBoundingRect()
        # r_rect = self.selected_hw.sceneBoundingRect()
# 
        # rectitem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(br_rect)
        # rectitem.setBrush(Qt.red)
        # self.viewer._scene.addItem(rectitem)
# 
        # rectitem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(sbr_rect)
        # rectitem.setBrush(Qt.green)
        # self.viewer._scene.addItem(rectitem)
# 
        # rectitem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(r_rect)
        # rectitem.setBrush(Qt.blue)
        # self.viewer._scene.addItem(rectitem)


     def calc_rotated_coords(self):
        # center point
        cx = self.selected_hw.rect().center().x()
        cy = self.selected_hw.rect().center().y()

        # rotation angle
        theta = math.radians(angle)

        rotated_corners = []
        for item in self.temp_list:
            x = item.x()
            y = item.y()

            temp_x = x - cx
            temp_y = y - cy

            rot_x = temp_x * math.cos(theta) + temp_y * math.sin(theta)
            rot_y = -temp_x * math.sin(theta) + temp_y * math.cos(theta)

            rotated_corners.append([rot_x, rot_y])
        
        self.temp_list = rotated_corners

        print("\nPIXEL VALUES OF HW: \n{}".format(self.temp_list))
```

Comment: Since you're only applying a simple rotation, why don't you use [`setRotation()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation)? In any case, you can map local coordinates using [`mapToScene()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mapToScene). Besides that, your approach seems too convoluted and also "unsafe": every class relies too much on external and "temporary" attributes that are implicitly "assumed", which can possibly lead to name errors or memory leaks.

Comment: @musicamante - First of all, I'll keep in mind your suggestions. Thanks.
I tried to map the local coordinates using the mapToScene(). I added that line like that: 

`rect = self.selected_hw.mapToScene(self.selected_hw.sceneBoundingRect()).boundingRect()`  and this didn't give me the what I want. Corners of 'rect' is the bounding rect's corners, not the  exact rotated corners. It looks like [that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijvYrZNNYYJJcxPqN4KjakkHAbylW2ND/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The `sceneBoundingRect` is the rectangle occupied by the whole item, not the rectangle *of* the item: if the item is rotated, the bounding rect shown on the scene is different. You need to use `mapToScene` with the corners of the `rect()` of the item: for example, the top left corner is mapped using `self.selected_hw.mapToScene(self.selected_hw.rect().topLeft())`.

Comment: @musicamante I solved the problem. Thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: if you solved your problem, I suggest you to add your own answer and explain how you did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

I added the itemChange(self, change, value) event in to HighwayItem and if change is ItemPositionHasChanged, I calculated all items' corners as such:

```py
def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            top_left = self.mapToScene(self.rect().topLeft())
            top_right = self.mapToScene(self.rect().topRight())
            bottom_left = self.mapToScene(self.rect().bottomLeft())
            bottom_right = self.mapToScene(self.rect().bottomRight())

            changed_pos = [top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left]
        return super(HighwayItem, self).itemChange(change, value)
```